# How to share a photo album with people on restricted list on Facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy, photos, photo-sharing, album

How can I share photo album with friends from restricted list? When I go to `New Album` > `Custom Privacy` > `Specific people or list...` and manually add them in the text field, they still can't see the album, and Facebook says, the album is visible for `List1, Friend1, Friend2 except Restricted` (Friends 1 & 2 are on the restricted list).

Comment: Just for clarification.. you have friends on your "restricted" list (I'm assuming you don't want them to be able to see posts), but you are adding an album that you DO want them to see?... while still restricting them from status updates. Is that correct?

Comment: @NathanFrancy yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The only way they can see the photos are if they are tagged in them.

*Scenario*

You have a `restricted` list with your family and share your jokes to your friends. Having just come back from a family event, with family members from `restricted` list, you tag them in the respective photos. These users will now be able to see those photos.